# Why is this causing a NOCP?

Tags: c, arm, cortex-m

I have a problem with a hard fault on a M4F core processor. The problem is that I had an NOCP (attempt to execute a coprocessor instruction) fault. After removing this part of the code:

```
uint16_t SV_current_heater_1_6[6];
uint8_t HBTriacCurrentFlowP = 0;

if (SV_current_heater_1_6[0] > 2200){
    HBTriacCurrentFlowP |= 1;
}
else {
    HBTriacCurrentFlowP &= 254;
}
```

The problem disappeared. What did I do wrong, so I can learn for the next time from it?

Information:

Atollic TrueStudio, HAL, STM32F4xx

Comment: Show the declarations of all the identifiers in question.

Comment: It might be a good idea to show how you're compiling (e.g. hard-float/soft-float, target flags etc.)

Comment: Any floating point numbers involved?

Comment: Compiler settings are: 
Instruction set: Thumb2
Floating point: Hardware

No floating point numbers involved and 

    uint16_t SV_current_heater_1_6[6];
    uint8_t HBTriacCurrentFlowP = 0;

Comment: SV_current_heater_1_6 is a value polled directly from a 12bit ADC

Comment: -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -std=gnu11 -D

settings without the includes

Comment: Here's what I would do (and I spend all day on M4Fs): single-step the code at the assembly level, and look at the ARM instructions being executed. Is there any chance a spurious interrupt is happening, which in turn causes the hard fault?

Comment: There is everything done by polling (for now), so no interrupts, but in systick is a function call for the ProfiNET chip (was recommended in aplication note)... I will try it at the assembly lvl... and let you know

Comment: So does your application use floating points anywhere?

Comment: No, there is no dividing, no double or flout values, the main purpuse of the machine is to take data from spi ADC and GPIOs and send it via ProfiNET (modul connected via SPI).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, NOCP error in MPU unit initialisation code. My entire application does not use floating points. Turning on FPU using CPACR register solves the problem, but I wonder why something uses FPU when no float operations are used explicitly. Additionaly I have a problem with debugging it, since stepping over `ARM_MPU_SetRegion` (ARM CMSIS API) does produce bug and stepping though this function does not throw any error and program execution continues.